# Access Div Id placed in _Layout MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in MVC3. I have created a DIV in _Layout.cshtml file  for showing Error Messages and i have created a C# class ErrorMessage in Views Folder.

DIV in _layout.cshtml file:

This is class ErrorMessage code:

```
  public static class ErrorMessage
    {
        public static void Show(string message)
        {
            ErrorMessageDiv.InnerText = message;
        }
        public static void Hide()
        {
        }
    }
```

In the class ErrorMessage it gives error

> "ErrorMessageDiv does not exist in
>   current context"

Any idea how to do it in MVC3?

Comment: You have to remember that MVC3 does not work with "Code behind" or postbacks as regular WebForms does. All the information the View (cshtml) requires, has to be passed to the View from a controller (or async with javascript)

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a section of code in _layout.cshtml that looks for an error message in the TempData collection using a specific key.

Then in your controller, if an error has occurred, add the error text to the TempData and it will be rendered.

Here is an example:

In your controller, check for some error and add to the TempData:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        bool isError = true;

        if (isError)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "There has been an error";
            // Or if you want to use the ErrorMessage class
            // ErrorMessage.ShowError("There has been an error");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Then in your master _layout.cshtml template

```
<body>

@if (TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
{
    <div class="Error">
        @TempData["ErrorMessage"]
    </div>
}

@RenderBody()
```

The TempData will remove the value from itself after it has been accessed once.

If you still wish to use the ErrorMessage class then change to wrap the TempData.

```
public static class ErrorMessage
{
   public static void ShowError(string message)
   { 
      TempData["ErrorMessage"] = message;
   }
}
```

Comment: In my application, I have many Controllers and Models. Actually i want to create a single class for showing an error message inside Div presented in layout file. I don't if it is possible in MVC3?

Comment: @user664195. I have updated the answer to include your existing ErrorMessage class. In MVC there is no way of acquiring the View elements because the pattern dictates that the Controller and Model, should not know anything about the View.